# Drawing on a JPanel without repainting background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, glasspane

I have an algorithm that displays pretty fractals on a JPanel. I want to be able to show gridline 'crosshairs' on the fractal panel whenever a user hovers his mouse on the panel.

I have achieved this with a quick, simple method for drawing on stuff which goes like this (`fractal` is the name of the fractal JPanel):

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = fractal.getGraphics();
    // <problematic part>
    //   This is computationally expensive to do. It takes a good 0.2 seconds.
    //   This must be done to clear 'old' crosshairs
    fractal.repaint();
    // </problematic part>
            
    Color c = fractal.getColourScheme().getGridlineColour();
    g.setColor(new Color(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), 50));
            
    // Draw crosshairs around the mouse's current point
    g.drawLine(e.getX(), 0, e.getX(), fractal.getHeight());
    g.drawLine(0, e.getY(), fractal.getWidth(), e.getY());
}
```

As illustrated, I have to repaint() in order to clear any old crosshairs.

I have a feeling I need to paint my crosshairs on something like a Glass Pane to go on top of my JPanel - however, JPanel doesn't provide a Glass Pane. JRootPane does though - can I use this instead?

#### P.S.

Currently I'm painting the fractal pixel by pixel with lots of little `Line2D`s. I will eventually change this to producing a `BufferedImage` - in which case, would this problem even matter?

Comment: Use a `BufferedImage`

Comment: Wouldn't it still be better to draw lines on a separate glass panel as  not to repaint - even if it is a `BufferedImage`?

Comment: Well, there is `clearRect`

Comment: Meh, I'll just use `BufferedImage`. If it lags *at all* when I move my mouse in fullscreen mode, I'll come back complaining =P

Comment: Yeah, although I'm caching the BufferedImage, and only regenerating it when absolutely necessary, I still get poor visual performance from the crosshairs. I'll need to rethink how this gets painted.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea of using a glass pane would solve your problem permanently. It would no longer matter how you choose to draw the fractal itself, or whether it is displayed in a JPanel or any other type of component. Each object should really be responsible for it's own data and actions, so a different object really would probably be a good design choice.

That being said, you will still need to repaint the glass pane.
You should be able to use the `public void repaint(long tm, int x,
                    int y,
                    int width,
                    int height)` method to only repaint certain parts of the panel, instead of repainting the whole thing.

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) states:

> Adds the specified region to the dirty region list if the component is
>   showing. *The component will be repainted after all of the currently
>   pending events have been dispatched*.